# C++ Cannot template abstract factory singleton without undefined error

Tags: singleton, undefined, factory

I'm trying to create an AbstractFactory class that is templated on the base class. The abstract factory is a singleton but when I declare it for a baseclass I get an undefined error. This system works when AbstractFactory isn't templated and has a fixed BaseClass but that defeats the object of the abstraction...

Here's my AbstractFactory singleton class:

```
template <class TBaseClass>
class AbstractFactory
{
public:
    static AbstractFactory &Instance()
    {
        return m_instance;
    }

    std::string Register(const std::string &key, const std::function<TBaseClass*()> &fcn)
    {
        if (m_map.find(key) == m_map.end())
        {
            m_map[key] = fcn;
            return key;
        }
        else
        {
            return "__ERROR";
        }
    }

    TBaseClass *Create(const std::string &key)
    {
        if (m_map.find(key) != m_map.end())
        {
            return m_map[key]();
        }
        else
        {
            return nullptr;
        }
    }

    void PrintClasses()
    {
        std::string msg = "Classes = [ ";
        for (auto it = m_map.begin(); it != m_map.end(); it++)
        {
            if (it != m_map.begin())
                msg += ", ";
            msg += it->first;
        }
        msg += " ]";
        std::cout << msg << "\n";
    }

    AbstractFactory(AbstractFactory &rhs) = delete;
    void operator=(const AbstractFactory &rhs) = delete;

protected:
    AbstractFactory()
    {
        std::cout << "Factory Constructor\n";
    }
    static AbstractFactory m_instance;
    std::unordered_map<std::string, std::function<TBaseClass*()>> m_map;
};
```

Here are the BaseClass and BaseClassImpl (derived class) classes:

```
class BaseClass
{
public:
    BaseClass()
    {
    }

    // static id -- needs to be here to statically register derived classes with factory
    static std::string m_id;

protected:
};


// *****************************************************************************************************************

// Derived class 

class BaseClassImpl : public BaseClass
{
public:
    BaseClassImpl() : BaseClass()
    {
    }

    // derived class creator function
    static BaseClass *create()
    {
        auto *ptr = new BaseClass;
        return ptr;
    }
protected:

};
```

The AbstractFactory singleton is initialised for BaseClass with a static declaration:

```
template <>
AbstractFactory<BaseClass> AbstractFactory<BaseClass>::m_instance;
```

Then the BaseClassImpl is registered with the factory using a static declaration for the BaseClass id member:

```
std::string BaseClass::m_id = AbstractFactory<BaseClass>::Instance().Register(
    "FirstImpl", 
    []()
    {
        return BaseClassImpl::create();
    });
```

Finally my main function is as follows...

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::cout << "START\n";

    // Print available classes in the BaseClass factory
    AbstractFactory<BaseClass>::Instance().PrintClasses();

    // create ptr to instance of BaseClass
    auto obj = AbstractFactory<BaseClass>::Instance().Create("FirstImpl");
    
    std::cout << "END\n";
}
```

However, the error I get is:

```
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/main.dir/main.o: warning: relocation against `_ZN15AbstractFactoryI9BaseClassE10m_instanceE' in read-only section `.text._ZN15AbstractFactoryI9BaseClassE8InstanceEv[_ZN15AbstractFactoryI9BaseClassE8InstanceEv]'
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/main.dir/main.o: in function `AbstractFactory<BaseClass>::Instance()':
main.cpp:(.text._ZN15AbstractFactoryI9BaseClassE8InstanceEv[_ZN15AbstractFactoryI9BaseClassE8InstanceEv]+0x7): undefined reference to `AbstractFactory<BaseClass>::m_instance'
/usr/bin/ld: warning: creating DT_TEXTREL in a PIE
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/main.dir/build.make:104: main] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:97: CMakeFiles/main.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:103: all] Error 2
```

It seems that the AbstractFactory singleton hasn't be initialised but I'm not sure why...